# How do I implement two types comparison in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I found [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024) solution on how to compare two types in Typescript.
For instance, I have the following:

```js
type Department = {
  id?: number
  name: string
}

type Office = {
  id?: number
  name: string
  kind: string
}

class TDbHandler<T> implements IDbHandler<T> {
  private static instance: any
  private constructor() { }


  public static GetInstance<T>(): IDbHandler<T> {
    type Equals<T, S> = [T] extends [S]              // <<< THIS COLLATION
      ? ([S] extends [T] ? true : false)
      : false
    
    type a = Equals<T, Department>
    if(a === true)                                   // <<< FAILS HERE
      this.instance = new TDbHandler<Department>()
    else
      this.instance = new TDbHandler<Office>()

    return this.instance
  }

  // other methods
}
```

How do I implement type comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *cannot* use a types at runtime.

The error you are getting is:

```
'a' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.(2693)
```

All type information is removed during the compile step. This is why you cannot treat a type as a runtime value. It just doesn't actually exists in the compiled output.

If you want to change your code path based on the type of a a variable, then you need to do runtime checks on that value. The type system is there just to make you are doing legal things with all those runtime value according to all the possible types that value could be.

```
// check if the department specific property exists
if ('kind' in myValue) {
  this.instance = new TDbHandler<Department>()
} else {
  this.instance = new TDbHandler<Office>()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Alex, but I don't understand where do they get the result of type comparison at the link I attached. They post examples there `type X=Equals<{x:any},{x:number}>;//true`. How do they know it is true?

Comment: You would `X` in your generic types that describe what your code does, and how your code transforms those types. You still have to write the runtime code to do it, though.